# transfer file/output from a sandbox within a ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, file-transfer

Situation:
I am at my local computer trying to access a specific server from the lab.
To do so, first I need to SSH into the lab system

```
ssh -l username lab_server
```

Second, once I am at the lab system, I need to SSH to the server

```
ssh server_a
```

There are two things I want to do from this point:

1. I want to transfer some files from server_a to my local computer.
2. I want to save some terminal output(they are too big to use copy and paste) to my local computer

I just wonder how I could achieve 1. and 2. above. Thanks in advance.

Additional information:
The output I want to save is from mongo database. More specifically, after using

```
db.collection.find()
```

it would return the data from this collect and I would like save these data into my local machine.

Comment: Check out `scp` or `sftp` for file transfer, the `-J` option of `ssh` for jumping through your lab server and `script` for saving your terminal output. There are manual pages for all of those commands.

Comment: could you give me an concrete example on how to use the -J option? I read the instruction from the manual but still fail to comprehend how to proceed.

Comment: Sure. Basically you'd go `ssh -J user@lab.server.host.com user@server-a.host.com`. If you set up your user `ssh_config` you can go `ssh server_a` directly. 
Much more info here https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SSH_jump_host#Setup

Comment: for the mongodb part you can put your commands in a file and save the resulting output with input/output redirection: `mongo < commands.js > db-output.log`